# Static Variable Call from different classes

Tags: c#, class, static, null

So Class 1 is  called before Class2. Sfile in class 1 contains text and I verified that. While using it in class2 it is null. I know I'm missing something, just can't remember what. Thanks!

```
public static Class1{
     public static StreamWriter Sfile;

internal static void Function1(){
      StreamWriter Sfile = new StreamWriter(str1, true);
      Sfile.Write(Text)
      }
    }

public partial class Class2{

private void Function2(){
      StreamWriter PrintField=Class1.Sfile;
      //Sfile is null;         
       }
    }
```

Comment: Please add a tag indicating the language.

Comment: You haven't initialized the `sfile` in class1.

Comment: Maybe just use this in the internal function `Sfile = new StreamWriter(str1, true);` ! You are declaring a local variable otherwise !

Comment: In future, please format your code carefully before posting a question. See http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Function1` declares a *local* variable called `Sfile`, which hides the static field. So you've given the local variable a non-null value, but not the static field.

Change `Function1` like this:

```
internal static void Function1()
{
    Sfile = new StreamWriter(str1, true);
    Sfile.Write(Text);
}
```

... and now you won't get the same problem. It's still horrible code for other reasons, but at least `Sfile` won't be null.

Comment: `It's still horrible code for other reasons` - could you perhaps include those reasons in the answer? Perhaps the code from `Class1` is called from other locations and it being static like this actually serves a purpose?

Comment: @aevitas: There are too many reasons to list, to be honest - they'd dwarf the *actual* question, and I don't have the time right now either.